# Recommendation: Migrating PostgreSQL data 2 WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, postgresql, migration

I search for easiest way for migrating from custom CMS builded upon PostgreSQL to WordPress CMS.

I don't search for ready-quick answer, but some guidance, approach explanation etc.

Also, if someone here is sure that his approach is successful, then we can work together (with some money arrangement).

Thank you

Comment: This question is highly opinionated and likely to attact close votes, but instead of voting I am going to say don't do it!! Wordpress is a horribly bloated mess. Then postgresql is a far superior database than mysql. Moving data from postgresql to mysql is a step backwards.

Comment: Without information on the structure of the custom CMS I don't see how any advice can be give. Except for the advice e4c5 gave, which I tend to agree with.

Comment: I understand, but my clients wants this. And I agree with them. There is no problem with database, but with custom CMS builded upon with. Developers of those CMS does not work anymore, so they are in big problem. And they want WP /:

Current CMS does not have categories but only tags and every search option is based on tags, there is no categories. 

But also there is a numerous post types - audio, video, default text etc.

What info someone of you need to give me better advice?

Comment: I guess you could first [convert your PostGre database to MySQL](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php) then start to work with your current tables to insert data into Wordpress. You'll basicaly need to work on `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`, I suggest you to [learn a bit about this here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: @vard Thank you. I can export db in csv format for example and use WP All Import, but my problem is: two languages, which id's are in separated table then table with data (post title, tag, body), and authors table is also separated from this.
Also table with data have multiple rows for same article, for example I have:

id33 article title
id33 article content
id33 article tags

etc :/

Comment: @Eager2Learn For multilangue you should first consider what plugin you'll use to handle it in WP. For example with WPML, the post is duplicated in `wp_posts` and the ID reference between the original and translition is handled in `wp_icl_translations`. For the multiple instances of content, you'll have to see if you want them to be considered as post meta (one meta per row) or merge them in the post content through script. I think it'll be a lot of work, so depends of the amount of data you have it could be better to do this manually.

Comment: @vard 16 thousand posts :). So any kind of help is appreciated, even a "good luck" is good :)

Comment: Well, good luck :) I recommend you to learn a bit how Worpdress is working from the inside (the whole postmeta system and how your chosen translation plugin works) and make a table plan first to know where should be any of your data. Maybe check on qTranslate for multilingual, it may be a bit easier to handle on the DB side. It would be hard to help further without knowing the DB structure of your CMS, but you can still ask here for any specific question about WP.

Comment: @vard What do you mean is it possible to parse on some way old website (based on old CMS) via some kind of HTML parser and then those data use for import into WordPress?

If you know such kind of app or software please advice

Comment: No there is no parser for that, you're using a custom table structure in your custom cms, so you'll have to write your own script.